# Get variable from string generated by jQuery serialize

Tags: jquery, serialization

How can I get a variable's value from a string generated by jQuery's `.serialize()` method? Is there a native function to do this?

e.g.

`item1=foobar&item2=somethingelse`

where `item1` is the variable of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a native way, but you can get the `unserialize` function from here: https://gist.github.com/rcmachado/242617

And run: `$.unserialize('item1=foobar&item2=somethingelse')`

Which returns an array. You can even do this:

```
$.unserialize('item1=foobar&item2=somethingelse')['item1'];
```

to return "foobar"